# SQL Server 3 month from now

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL select statement to retrieve all employees that their enddate contract will end three month from now and only three month not more or less

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  "3 months from now" is ambiguous.  Consider Jan 31.  3 months later would be April 31 . . . but that date does not exist.

Comment: employee contract expired on 01/09/2017 so i need a function to know the end duration of the contract before 3 months

Comment: Clarify the specs first: 3 months from now is not a mathematical description. Most likely you want either e.g. 90 days, or an heuristic calculation that will find the next valid date N months from now. You can use the business logic from the standard Java 8 libraries under `java.time.LocalDate.plusMonths(long)`: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java#l1295

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean by 3 months from now.  If you mean on that exact date, then:

```
WHERE my_date_column = cast(dateadd(month, 3, getdate()) as date)
```

Note the cast to date to remove the time component.  This is ambiguous and under some circumstances might miss employees or count them twice.

If you want employees whose contract ends in the 3rd month from today, then use:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, getdate(), my_date_column) = 3
```

So, if this is January, this will return employees whose contract ends any time in April.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(DAY, +90, GETDATE())
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, +3, GETDATE())
```

**OR**

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, my_date_column, GETDATE()) <= 3
```

Comment: DATEADD(month,3,getdate()) is better.

Comment: @TriV ... Yupp :)